# Java - RSA Public Key from PEM File - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo

Tags: java, security, rsa, bouncycastle, java-security

I have PEM file which is a RSA PRIVATE KEY and I am reading the Private Key and Public using the code below ::

```
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(//pem);

            PEMReader pemReader = new PEMReader(reader);
            final KeyPair keyPair = (KeyPair) pemReader.readObject();
            pKey = keyPair.getPublic();
            RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) pKey;
            rsaPublicKey.getEncoded();
            Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rsaPublicKey.getEncoded()))
```

This code runs fine when Running as Standalone Java

However when running as Webapplication , I am getting the below Error::

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet MYSERVER threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo
        at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSAPublicKey.getEncoded(Unknown Source)
```

Library :: bcprov-jdk16-143

Any clues ??

Comment: Did you check for permissions on the file or the key store .. since the web app may be running under a different account.

Comment: I load the pem value   as String Object. I successfully get the KeyPair but after that extracting the Base64 encode ..it fails.....

Comment: Please check your classpath for duplicate BC jars. e.g. the webserver may have its own bcprov jar, or there might be one installed in your JRE's lib/ext folder.

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you miss some [Bouncy Castle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html) jar dependencies in your code.

Comment: Nopes bc is part of WEB-INF/lib - infact org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCERSAPublicKey and org/bouncycastle/asn1/x509/SubjectPublicKeyInfo are part of the same jar

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Bouncy Castle needs to be registered as a valid crypto provider in Java. You can do it either in code like this:

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
```

or globally in Java like [this](https://makeinjava.com/install-bouncy-castle-provider-configuring-java-runtime-example/).

Comment: I don't think you get that exception when failing to register the provider. And anyone he's not using the bouncycastle provider in the code fragment provided.

Comment: I actually load the bouncy castle provider..doesnt give any errror-  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());